# xfakebold or amsbsy to get heavy bold for mtpro2

Tags: packages, bold, mtpro

This question is a follow-up of this question [Increase a bit the bold symbols in mtpro2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605470/increase-a-bit-the-bold-symbols-in-mtpro2).

Considering this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\begin{document}
\[\int_{x=a}^{x=0} \biggl[\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\biggr]\,dx\]
\[\int_{1}^{2} \pmb{\biggl[}\frac{\ln x}{x+1}\pmb{\biggr]}\,dx\]

\end{document}
```

with a zoom of **337.5 %** (working with TeXworks) the fake bold is imperceptible (you can see the red rectangles).

[image]

With a zoom of **1708.59 %** we have this:

[image]

> Is there a chance to fix the fake bold well?

Looking this old [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266890/redefining-pmb-for-nicer-results) and the answer of very nice user @David Carlisle, there is a trick to improved `\pmb` in `amsbsy`:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=10000}]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsuet} {T1} {wesu}{bx}{sl}

% I get metafont errors from these settings?
%\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
%\pdfpkresolution=8000

\makeatletter
\def\pmb@@#1#2#3{\leavevmode\setboxz@h{#3}%
\dimen@-\wdz@
\kern-.5\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\raise.4\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.2\ex@\raise.3\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.15\ex@\raise.2\ex@\copy\z@
\kern\dimen@\kern.25\ex@\box\z@
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\fbox{{
$\bm n n$
$\pmb{\mathsuet n}\, \mathsuet n$
}}
\end{document}
```

> Is it a possible solution, and how must be modificated the whole code?

**Note**: *The square brackets written in bold also appear in John David Jackson's textbook used in University, Classical Electrodynamics, in relation to the retarded potentials.*

Comment: The fakebold works by overprinting and offsetting so you're going to always have these artifacts with any sort of fake bolding. amsbsy doesn't include the components of the large brackets so that won't be much use either. You'd need to find a font with heavier weight extendable brackets. I don't know if such a thing exists.

Comment: @DonHosek Thank you very much for your response. I thought if exist a patch, a macro o anything to get, for the xfakebold package, just one character considering that there is also a \setBold[0.3] hence the size of the thickness. In mtpro2 not exist an heavier brackets (see the link for the first part of the question).

Comment: @Sebastiano - Just to make sure that I understand your formatting objective: You're looking to render just the square brackets in a bolder/heavier font weight, but not the rest. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: @Mico Correct interpretation; I would like to find a strategy that bypasses the absence of the characters that have a very light bold and that enables the curly script characters of mtpro2 full version to have the bold option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've indicated that you have access to the "full" `mtpro2` package, you could make use of the `\hm` ("heavy math") macro of the [bm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bm) package to achieve your formatting objective.

Observe that the application of `\hm` results in a *much heavier* "look" of curly braces, square brackets, and round parentheses than what may be achieved via an application of `\bm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}          % for "alignat*" environment
\usepackage{newtxtext,mtpro2} % Times Roman text and math fonts
\usepackage{bm}               % for "\bm" and "\hm" macros

\begin{document}
\addtolength\jot{1ex} % just for this example
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\biggl[\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\biggr]
  &&\Biggl\{\biggl[\Bigl({}\cdots\Bigr)\biggr]\Biggr\} 
  &&\text{default font weight}\\
&\bm{\biggl[}\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\bm{\biggr]}
  &&\bm{\Biggl\{\biggl[\Bigl(\cdots\Bigr)\biggr]\Biggr\}}
  &&\text{\texttt{\string\bm} (``bold math'')}\\
&\hm{\biggl[}\frac{1}{\dot{x}}\hm{\biggr]}
  &\qquad&\hm{\Biggl\{\biggl[\Bigl(\cdots\Bigr)\biggr]\Biggr\}}
  &\qquad&\text{\texttt{\string\hm} (``heavy math'')}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Impressive and excellent. So I will have to change all my `\boldsymbol`(s) used in the book with the use of the `bm` package. I remember, and I hope I didn't make a mistake, that with `bm` I was having problems with the compilation. Could you possibly verify :-) if it works :-) :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - I'm not sure if I'm in a position to tell you what you should or shouldn't do. :-) For sure, though, don't hand-edit all instances of `\boldsymbol`; instead, you could run something like `\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\bm{#1}}` or `\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\hm{#1}}` (and, of course, load the `bm` package). That way, if you should ever decide *not* to employ the `mtpro2` math font package, you needn't convert back from `\bm` or `\hm` to `\boldsymbol`.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much for your precious contributes. +1 for all.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code in my structure-mod.sty and I have this mistaken that I am not able to fix it. It is: `! LaTeX Error: Command \heavymath already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.89 ...ath{\@nomath\heavymath\mathversion{heavy}}
                                                  
?` I sent you a postmail :)

Comment: Very kindest Mico, have you found the solution :-)?

Comment: @Sebastiano - I'm still looking into this. The ordering of the packages has to be `amsmath`-`newtxtext`-`mtpro2`-`bm`. Unfortunately, when I modify your `stucture-mod.sty` style file to implement these changes, the initial error message goes away, but then I get a `! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.` error message. I'm still trying to figure out why that's the case.

Comment: There is a reply :-))))))...

Comment: Hi very kind Mico. I have sent you a mail. 